# Trouble assigning value to react state from a nested JSON file

Tags: reactjs

I created to select components from Material UI, one for the make and the other for the model of a car. The first select assigns the new state for the make, but I am having trouble assigning the model which is an array inside an object.

This is the JSON data

```
[
    {
        "value": "ACURA",
        "title": "Acura",
        "models": [
            {
                "value": "CL_MODELS",
                "title": "CL Models (4)"
            },
            {
                "value": "2.2CL",
                "title": " - 2.2CL"
            },
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": "ALFA",
        "title": "Alfa Romeo",
        "models": [
            {
                "value": "ALFA164",
                "title": "164"
            },
            {
                "value": "ALFA8C",
                "title": "8C Competizione"
            },
            {
                "value": "ALFAGT",
                "title": "GTV-6"
            },
            {
                "value": "MIL",
                "title": "Milano"
            },
            {
                "value": "SPID",
                "title": "Spider"
            },
            {
                "value": "ALFAOTH",
                "title": "Other Alfa Romeo Models"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": "AMC",
        "title": "AMC",
        "models": [
            {
                "value": "AMCALLIAN",
                "title": "Alliance"
            },
            {
                "value": "CON",
                "title": "Concord"
            },
            {
                "value": "EAGLE",
                "title": "Eagle"
            },
            {
                "value": "AMCENC",
                "title": "Encore"
            },
            {
                "value": "AMCSPIRIT",
                "title": "Spirit"
            },
            {
                "value": "AMCOTH",
                "title": "Other AMC Models"
            }
        ]
    },
//more date here
]
```

In my JS file, I import from the JSON file like: `import Cars from "./../../lib/cars.json";`.

This is some of the code in the JS file, where the make and model are to be selected.

```
    const [make, setMake] = React.useState("");
    const [model, setModel] = React.useState("");
    
//assign make
    const handleMakeChange = (event) => {
      setMake(event.target.value);
      console.log("MAKE: ", event.target.value);
    };
    
//assign model
    const handleModelChange = (event) => {
      setModel(event.target.value);
      console.log("MODEL: ", event.target.value);
    };
    
    //some code here
    
    {/* Make form */}
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="make-controlled-open-select-label">
        Select make
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="make-controlled-open-select-label"
        id="make-controlled-open-select"
        name="make"
        open={openMake}
        onClose={handleMakeClose}
        onOpen={handleMakeOpen}
        value={make}
        onChange={handleMakeChange}
       >
       <MenuItem value="">
         <em>None</em>
       </MenuItem>
       {Cars.map((item) => (
         <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.title}>
           {item.title}
         </MenuItem>
       ))}
       </Select>
     </FormControl>
    
    {/* Model form */}
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="model-controlled-open-select-label">
        Select model
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="model-controlled-open-select-label"
        id="model-controlled-open-select"
        name="model"
        open={openModel}
        onClose={handleModelClose}
        onOpen={handleModelOpen}
        value={model}
        onChange={handleModelChange}
      >
       <MenuItem value="">
         <em>None</em>
       </MenuItem>
       {Cars.map((item) => (
         <p key={item.value}>
           {item.models.map((car) => (
             <MenuItem key={car.value} value={car.title}>
               {car.title}
             </MenuItem>
           ))}
          </p>
       ))}
     </Select>
   </FormControl>
```

I am usually getting `undfined` for the model state or `Material-UI: A component is changing the controlled value state of Select to be uncontrolled. Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).`. I am not sure if the problem is in the way I am mapping the model or something else.

Comment: Is it possible to move your code to stackblitz. We can have better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-msnsbx?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using that `<p>` tag somewhere? Its causing the issue actually while onChange. Try below code for Model Select .

```
<Select
            labelId="model-controlled-open-select-label"
            id="model-controlled-open-select"
            name="model"
            open={openModel}
            onClose={handleModelClose}
            onOpen={handleModelOpen}
            value={model}
            onChange={handleModelChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            {Cars.map(item => (
                item.models.map(car => (
                  <MenuItem key={car.value} value={car.title}>
                    {car.title}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I always assumed mapping an array should happen inside `{}`. That's why the `item.model.map` had `{}` of it's own inside the `Car.map{}`.